# Import package as another

Tags: scala, import, package

Let's say I have a Scala project with a bunch of case classes under package `com.example.a.b.c`. I want to import all these classes into a package `com.example.c` (which contains a few more non-conflicting case classes) so that anywhere else in my project, I only need to `import com.example.c._` to use every case class both from `com.example.c` and `com.example.a.b.c`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you just trying to organize your code in a logical way, and do you have control of the organization? If so you can define your `com.example.a.b.c` case classes in a trait (or traits) and then write `package object c extends ThatTrait`. Scalaz for example uses this approach extensively.

Comment: That's an interesting approach! I'd have to discuss it with the team since I actually don't have control over `com.example.a.b.c`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is discussion of adding an *export* mechanism which would do what you want, but it's not clear whether that will happen.

In any case, for now the only way is to

- Define the type of every class
- Set a val equal to every object

So for example,

```
package bar
case class Foo(i: Int) {}
```

would need to be mimicked in another package with

```
package object baz {
  type Foo = bar.Foo
  val Foo = bar.Foo
}
```

When faced with this, people usually just settle for an extra import or two.

Comment: Thanks Rex! Accepted! I agree that the extra imports are the easy solution, but it's a real pain when you need these everywhere and end up with, say, 4 extra import statements. And for maintenance purposes, I'd rather have the breaking changes in a single place.

Answer (score 1):

The import statement in scala just tells the compiler where to find other classes like in java, not like the #include directive in C/C++ where the compiler physically copies the entire header file. If you want to use the case classes from `com.example.a.b.c`, you should import them from their own package as this is the conventional way.